a notion formula that sums up all the points in a chart only if the item in the charts status is done
I would like to create a formula in notion that looks at all the items I have in a chart. I want it to sum all of the values in the second row of the chart together if the status of the item is "done"

Use a Rollup function for the value that you want to sum and set to sum.
